# CAPS LOCK remains 'ON' & Battery Discharges after Turning Off Laptop

Tags: laptop, battery, capslock

Laptop Model - Lenovo Ideapad U410

Issue: Every time I switch off my laptop, the CAPS LOCK light switches on automatically and the battery drains almost completely overnight.
This issue started recently after the display fiber frame bezel was replaced and the windows were re-installed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the BIOS settings were changed.
For the Caps Lock issue check the BIOS settings to see if it specifies Caps Lock should be on at boot. 
For the power issue you either have a bad battery or the system is keeping the USB ports powered and a device is draining the battery overnight.  There should be a setting in the BIOS for this or you could ensure that nothing is plugged in as a test.

Comment: Another possibility: the laptop isn't actually being powered off, just going into a sleep state.  Check the power settings for what action the power button is now set to perform.  Could also be a network connection or WiFi being kept active.